# Keycode for "hide keyboard button"

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, keylistener, onkeypress

I am trying to intercept the "Hide keyboard button" (seen in many phones to hide a keyboard in `EditText`). I searched everywhere but could not find the correct keycode for that. I assumed it's the same as the back button (as it replaces the same button), but it doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: `onBackPressed()` @Override method will work for you and you can add functionality on this method

Comment: @RakeshKumar - No, it doesn't. onBackPressed() will not get called when keyboard is up

Answer (score 0):

This code can hide soft keyboard.

InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getActivity().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);

Comment: I dont want to hide keyboard. Pressing that key hides it automatically. I want to intercept that and add more code while dismissing keyboard